# Azure Event Hubs Token Expired when running application inside docker container

Tags: azure, docker, datetime, asp.net-core, azure-eventhub

Using the Azure "EventHubClient" library in .NET Core 2.2 to send events when running my solution locally via IIS Express, I have no issues. However when running my solution inside a docker container I get the following error:

> 'Put token failed. status-code: 401, status-description: ExpiredToken:
>   The token is expired. Expiration time: '2019-08-16 18:25:27Z'.'

When checking the clock running inside my docker container using:

`docker exec -it {ContainerID} date`

or via DateTime.UtcNow, I get something like: {08/16/2019 17:26:53}

Clearly before the expiry date as they are both in UTC format. This has left me perplexed.

My code to send to event hub:

```
public EventHubSink(EventHubClient eventHubClient)
{
    _eventHubClient = eventHubClient;
}

public async Task SendToEventHub(string message)
{
   try
   {
       string serializedLogPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
       await _eventHubClient.SendAsync(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedLogPayload)));
   } 
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      Console.WriteLine($"Failed to send message to eventHub: ${e.Message}");
   }
}
```

Where _eventHubClient is being initialized in another class as follows:

```
eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(config["EventHub:ConnectionString"]);
```

Comment: can you post the code

Comment: I have edited the question to include my code

Comment: This sounds related: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37283

Comment: Did you only try in Windows-based containers or also in Linux-based?

Comment: Yes this is more or less my issue exactly. But I am only using Linux based on containers. Anyways simply restarting docker seemed to fix the issue for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how this happened but it seemed the system clock inside my docker containers was a full day behind. Anyways I used the following steps on my windows machine and it seemed to solve my problem:

1. Right click on the clock and select adjust time date
2. Toggle the "Set the Time Automatically" on and off
3. Restart docker

And I am now getting the correct UTC time from within my containers